# Value was either too large or too small for an Int32 Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, integer

I am trying to add `Mobile Number` to my column which is of 10 digit

But it is giving me error as

> Value was either too large or too small for an Int32

Here is the code

```
drpartyInfo[0]["MOB_NUM"] = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Record["MOB_NUM"].ToString())
    ? DBNull.Value : (object)Convert.ToInt32(e.Record["MOB_NUM"].ToString());
```

Comment: Just to be a bit clearer in respect to all answers given here. If you have and know the upper/lower bounds of the values, you should choose the smallest binary datatype that fits (`short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`). Databases *LOVE* those types, they occupy a fixed amount of bytes and can be ordered/indexed easier. A `string` (`varchar`) is not as easy to handle, so as a rule of thumb avoid `string` if you can. On the other hand if you have *less than ~10 million rows* in a table the difference will be barely noticeable. This is just a side note and not meant to be an answer.

Comment: @pid: so according to you which datatype will be suitable here for mobile number?

Comment: 10 digits means the lower bound is 0 and the upper bound is 9,999,999,999. That fits into a `long` (`Int64`). Whatever number `n` fits into `log2(n) + 1` bits. Up that number to 8, 16, 32, 64 and you have the least type you require.

Comment: You don't want to store phone numbers as numbers unless you store the prefix (area, country code) separately.

Comment: WAIT! If `MOB_NUM` is a phone number don't use an integer at all. It really is a *code* which must be stored in a string and not a *quantity*! My bad, where I live we don't say *mobile number* but simply *phone number*. Leading `0` cannot be stored in an integer of any sort! USE A STRING!!!

Comment: The only correct answer is **Ikram Turgunbaev**'s

Comment: what's wrong about my answer @pid I ill appreciate the correction

Comment: @MrVoid A phone number may have leading zeroes such as 00927849, which, when converted to any of the integer types becomes 927849. To no avail you can re-convert it to a string (or render it on a web page) and get the leading zeroes back.

Comment: very true, those digits will be lost, thanks

Answer (score 4):

Better you should use `long`, `string` or `byte array`.

You can refer this.

```
short.MaxValue:  32767
short.MinValue: -32768
ushort.MaxValue: 65535
ushort.MinValue: 0
int.MaxValue:    2,147,483,647
int.MinValue:   -2,147,483,648
uint.MaxValue:   4,294,967,295
uint.MinValue:   0
long.MaxValue:   9,223,372,036,854,775,807
long.MinValue:  -9,223,372,036,854,775,808
ulong.MaxValue:  18,446,744,073,709,551,615
```

You can use `unsigned` datatype, if you are sure that it will always be positive number.

Answer (score 2):

Mobile number can not be stored on int, change your type to string

Answer (score 2):

If your number is bigger than 2147483647, it can't be stored into a int32, use string or use a int64, I doubt your number is bigger than 9223372036854775807

Answer (score 1):

[`Int32.MaxValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.int32.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) is `2,147,483,647`.

If the mobile number is 10 digits long, there is a 79% chance it won't fit in an Int32. Try and Int64 (or UInt64) instead.